Uploading file to OpenAPI via openapi-ts
I am trying to upload a multipart file to a FastAPI server using OpenAPI to share the types for the upload.
This is my client:
import type { paths } from "./apiTypes";
import createClient from "openapi-fetch";

export let { GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, TRACE } = createClient<paths>(
  {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/",
  }
);

This is my upload file definition:
load_file_load_post: {
    requestBody: {
      content: {
        "multipart/form-data": components["schemas"]["Body_load_file_load_post"];
      };
    };
    responses: {...

Uploading from JS (the problem is here probably):
// formData is new FormData()
await POST('/load', {
  body: formData
})

FastAPI:
@app.post("/load")
async def load_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        file_content = await file.read()

For some reason FastAPI still says that I'm missing fileds (file).
